# Access private member of VBA class from another instance of same class

Tags: vba, class, oop

I have a VBA class module, `Foo`, which has a method which operates on another instance of class `Foo`. I want this method to be able to look at the private state of the other instance, as in the `CompareTo` function below.

```vb
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Foo"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False

Private SecretValue As Integer

Function CompareTo(ByVal You As Foo) As Integer
    Return Me.SecretValue - You.SecretValue
End Function
```

Unfortunately the above doesn't work because within the scope of `CompareTo`, the private state of `You` is not available.

In other (more) mainstream OO languages with which I am familiar (Java, C#, Kotlin, C++, etc.), the private members of a class are accessible to all instances of the class.

Questions:

- First, am I doing this wrong and is there a way for `Me` to see the private state of `You`?
- Second, if there is no way, what could justify this odd design choice?

Comment: That always struck me as an odd thing to do. The type of `Me` is the class' default interface, i.e. its public members - that excludes private fields. The way around that would be to implement a private interface, or to have a `Friend Property Get` accessor for the `SecretValue` -- I can't think of a way to constrain (other than by convention & discipline) the use of a private interface or a friend (essentially `internal` in C#) accessor within the same project.. cross-project references in VBA work, but require as many documents opened in the host application. #tradeoffs

Comment: Thanks @MathieuGuindon. It looks like `Friend` is *slightly* better than `Public` but more or less the same for all intents and purposes. What is a private interface?

Comment: Class modules are `Private` by default; VBA also supports `PublicNotCreatable` instancing mode, so technically one project could work with a private API and expose a public one for clients. Now, the "not creatable" part means the client code can't use the `New` operator to create instances of our classes, but that doesn't mean we can't have public factory methods in stateless default instances. Client code ends up looking like `Dim thing As ISomething`; `Set thing = Something.Create("yes, args!")`

Comment: ...and meanwhile `Something` also implements some `IInternalSomething` that mandates some `SecretValue` member, but that interface is private and the client code can't see it.